# App crashes immediately after start in release mode. System Policy: deny(1) dynamic-code-generation

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, code-signing-entitlements

I have the following issue. I have the app which crashes just after a LaunchScreen with the following errors in device log (I was able to find it only in console):

```
16:33:47.588355 +0300   kernel  Sandbox: MyApp(12565) System Policy: deny(1) dynamic-code-generationerror
16:33:47.588394 +0300   kernel  MyApp(12565) System Policy: MAP_JIT requires the dynamic-codesigning entitlement
```

There are no more info neither in crashlytics nor in Xcode. So I don't even see any stack traces or log outputs to identify the issue.
I have this issue only in release mode and only on some devices which can differ in iOS version and even model.

I have already tried to add `dynamic-codesigning` entitlement but there is no such entitlement in my Entitlements.plist but in build settings it has been enabled about 30 versions before and I have not fixed this issue.

Comment: so.. where do you do dynamic code generation in your app? Also, a google search for "MAP_JIT" is interesting.. Don't try to just add an entitlement, you should try to understand the error message first.

Comment: @Michael I just checked two possible places in the app CoreData and UIWebView. On all CoreData entities Codegen option is set to Manual/None. So it seems the problem is on UIWebView but why it works differently on devices (I mean this is not OS version or Model related crash)?